# Searching a database in Report Builder 3.0

Tags: reporting-services

I am not sure if this is possible in Report Builder or not.  I want to put a text box in a Report  Builder report and then search the database for a specific person and display that in a subreport.  Is this possible and, if so, how would you suggest I do it?  I have tried researching it online without success.

Comment: Your question doesn't make sense.  Are you saying you want the user to be able to type in values that then open up a sub report with the details of the value that was searched for?

Comment: Sounds like you want to use Parameters, although it's difficult to understand exactly what you want here.

Comment: Your question doesn't make sense. Are you saying you want the user to be able to type in values that then open up a sub report with the details of the value that was searched for?  Yes, I want to have text boxes for the first and last name of a person then click on a Search button that will run a query and return information and display it in a subreport.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## This part will produce a parameter into which your user can type whatever they want

You need to set up your report to use parameters.  You can set these parameters up to require user input either from manual entry or by picking from a pre-defined list.

Assuming you are returning your data using a SQL query, you can then reference these parameters in your dataset script.  If for example you had a parameter called `FirstName` and another called `Surname`, and you only wanted to return values in your data set that matched both exactly, you would reference these parameters like so:

```
select PersonID
      ,FirstName
      ,Surname
      ,OtherDetails
from PersonTable
where FirstName = @FirstName
  and Surname = @Surname
```

If you would rather have more of a 'search' type function, you can use the SQL `like` operator and wildcards, though bear in mind this will have a potentially very detrimental effect on your query performance:

```
select PersonID
      ,FirstName
      ,Surname
      ,OtherDetails
from PersonTable
where FirstName like '%'+@FirstName+'%'
  and Surname like '%'+@Surname+'%'
```

---

## This part shows you how to change that parameter so it provides a drop down menu.  ***This part is optional.***

If you want to provide a list of available options to select from, you can create a parameter that has a list of 'Available Values'.  These can either be manually typed in by yourself - hard coding them in to the report design - or you can make them data driven by basing the parameter on a second dataset.

To get that list of people, you would want to return the ID of the person you are looking for as well as the details that are end-user friendly to be visible in the report:

```
-- select distinct so we have no duplicates
select distinct PersonID as Value    -- Value is what is used to the query.  This ideally will be a uniquye identifier
               ,FirstName
                + ' '
                + Surname as Label   -- Label is what the user sees.  This can be a bit more verbose and detailed
from PersonTable
order by Surname                     -- Specify how you want the options ordered
        ,FirstName
```

If you set this dataset as the source by selecting `Get Values From A Query` in the parameter options, you will see the drop down list appear when you run the report.  Users can then select one, click `Run Report` and have their selection impact the data that is returned.

Comment: Thank you for the advice.  One other question.  Is there something in Report Builder 3.0 that I can use to have the user type in a value and then run the query off that?  I don't want to use a parameter drop-down because the selection is quite long.  I would like to use something like a text-box but when I tried that it would not let me type in the box.

Comment: That is what the first half of my answer does.  A parameter only offers a list of items if you tell it to, ie: by giving it a list or attaching it to a dataset as I have done in the second part of my answer.  If you just had a parameter called `@FirstName` with no options, users could type whatever they wanted into it and that value would be used in your query as above.  Try it out and see if it all makes sense.

Comment: It makes complete sense.  I am looking for some way in Report Builder to enable the user to type in something like a name and then the query goes to the database and finds the information that I want to display for that entity.  One of the databases that I am trying to do this with has about 220,000 records and that would be too much for user to scroll through looking for one particular record.

Comment: @donald.dougherty  That is literally what the first half of my answer is doing.  Just make the parameter and don't specify any values.  Then write your query as `select <Your Report Data> from Tables where LookupField = @ParameterName`.  Read and follow just the first paragraph and code example in my answer.  Just try it and you will see that it works.  Don't over think it.  Don't think you understand it all right now.  Just follow the first paragraph in my answer and you will have your report.

Comment: I understand that and I can do it with the parameter drop-down but I don't want the users to have to scroll through almost 250,000 items to find the one they want, I want them to be able to type in the ID number of what they want the status o(assuming they know the ID number) and click Search and it gives them the status.

Comment: @donald.dougherty  Good grief.  PLEASE read what I am saying and actually try to understand it.  THE FIRST HALF OF MY ANSWER SHOWS YOU HOW TO HAVE A PARAMETER ***WITH NO DROP DOWN SELECTION***.  If you follow just the first half, you will have a parameter your user can type whatever they want in and then run the report.

Comment: Thank you.  I really appreciate your help once I reread it.  I am pretty much  newbie to Report Builder and pretty much closed down when I saw the word parameter.

Comment: @donald.dougherty  In the future, try believing in yourself and taking things one simple step at a time.  90% of software development is really simple things stacked on top of other really simple things.  If this is the right answer for your question please Mark out as such for anyone else that comes to this site with the same requirements.

Comment: Thank you for your help.  I ran into a snag though.  For some reason when I run the report in Sharepoint where we host the reports the visible parameter for my search report is not showing up.  It works fine in Report Builder.

Comment: @donald.dougherty  Are you drilling through to this report from another that doesn't have any parameters?  If so, this is a known bug of SSRS and the workaround is to create a dummy parameter in the top report so the parameter bar shows up: https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/2903465/parameter-pane-is-not-visible-in-drillthrough-report-in-sharepoint-integrated-mode-in-ssrs

Comment: I found that out after I posted this comment.  I am going to set up a separate report to show him what it will look like and see what he thinks.  Thank you for all your help on this.

Comment: No worries @donald.dougherty  If this was the answer to your question please mark it as such for the benefit of others with the same question.